# How to add a changelog to a Cabal package?

Tags: haskell, cabal, hackage

I see that Hackage 2 has a changelog field. This is a feature I've wanted for a long time. But multiple Google searches have failed to find a single shred of documentation about how you *populate* this field. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I could not find documentation right away, but [code](https://github.com/haskell/hackage-server/blob/master/Distribution/Server/Packages/ChangeLog.hs):

There is no field for it, but it will simply look in the tarball for a file named `changelog`, `change_log` or `changes` (a file ending of `.txt`, `.md` and `.markdown` is allowed). Case does not matter.

Note that this file won't necessarily be added to the tarball by `cabal sdist` unless you also add it to the cabal file somehow.  One way to do this is by adding it to the `Extra-source-files:` field at the top-level of the cabal file.  e.g.:

```
Extra-Source-Files:  changelog.md
```

Cabal's [.cabal](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal-1.16.0/Cabal.cabal) file does this, and provides a good example.

Comment: Yay for documentation. :-S Does it matter whether the file is in the root?

Comment: Unfortunately, simply adding a changelog file to my package folder didn't do anything. It seems Cabal ignored the file and didn't include it in the tarball. How do I make it do that?

Comment: You need to add it to the `extra-source-files` field.